# "libunity.so" - Play Console Crash

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, admob, google-play-console

we've been getting this crash on play console on our hypercasual games up on google play console. We are unable to track it down to what may be causing it. Here is the stack trace.

We are using Unity3d for our games and Firebase Analytics, Crashlytics and Messaging alongside Google Admob and Applovin sdks.

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
pid: 0, tid: 4912 >>> com.dopegames.carsim <<<

backtrace:
  #00  pc 0x00000000004f850c  /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLES_mali.so
  #01  pc 0x0000000000475388  /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLES_mali.so
  #02  pc 0x00000000005e8234  /data/app/~~_9hlgqK-ziZ2hhvPVMlTeg==/com.dopegames.carsim-vUmgewFgMybM0yE8UyZdjQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so
  #03  pc 0x00000000005e7b70  /data/app/~~_9hlgqK-ziZ2hhvPVMlTeg==/com.dopegames.carsim-vUmgewFgMybM0yE8UyZdjQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so
  #04  pc 0x00000000005e6240  /data/app/~~_9hlgqK-ziZ2hhvPVMlTeg==/com.dopegames.carsim-vUmgewFgMybM0yE8UyZdjQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so
  #05  pc 0x00000000005c0678  /data/app/~~_9hlgqK-ziZ2hhvPVMlTeg==/com.dopegames.carsim-vUmgewFgMybM0yE8UyZdjQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so
  #06  pc 0x00000000005c57e8  /data/app/~~_9hlgqK-ziZ2hhvPVMlTeg==/com.dopegames.carsim-vUmgewFgMybM0yE8UyZdjQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so
  #07  pc 0x00000000005c5700  /data/app/~~_9hlgqK-ziZ2hhvPVMlTeg==/com.dopegames.carsim-vUmgewFgMybM0yE8UyZdjQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so
  #08  pc 0x00000000005ae6c0  /data/app/~~_9hlgqK-ziZ2hhvPVMlTeg==/com.dopegames.carsim-vUmgewFgMybM0yE8UyZdjQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so
  #09  pc 0x0000000000321cf4  /data/app/~~_9hlgqK-ziZ2hhvPVMlTeg==/com.dopegames.carsim-vUmgewFgMybM0yE8UyZdjQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so
  #10  pc 0x0000000000322458  /data/app/~~_9hlgqK-ziZ2hhvPVMlTeg==/com.dopegames.carsim-vUmgewFgMybM0yE8UyZdjQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so
  #11  pc 0x0000000000324b08  /data/app/~~_9hlgqK-ziZ2hhvPVMlTeg==/com.dopegames.carsim-vUmgewFgMybM0yE8UyZdjQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so
  #12  pc 0x000000000031928c  /data/app/~~_9hlgqK-ziZ2hhvPVMlTeg==/com.dopegames.carsim-vUmgewFgMybM0yE8UyZdjQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so
  #13  pc 0x0000000000331204  /data/app/~~_9hlgqK-ziZ2hhvPVMlTeg==/com.dopegames.carsim-vUmgewFgMybM0yE8UyZdjQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so
  #14  pc 0x000000000006f944  /data/app/~~_9hlgqK-ziZ2hhvPVMlTeg==/com.dopegames.carsim-vUmgewFgMybM0yE8UyZdjQ==/oat/arm64/base.odex
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.